# start specific firefox profile with batch and open url

Tags: batch-file, imacros

I have the code to open firefox profile. I am using shortcut on Desktop named profileA.

```
start "" /B  "C:\Users\UserA\Desktop\profileA"
```

But when I try to open a link via FireFox addon inside it I don't get the results I want.

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "imacros://run/?m=%23Current.iim"
```

It opens firefox again and inside it It opens this url...

How can I bypass this? If it's possible to do everything from batch without using a shortcut on desktop that would be better.

Comment: Currently your second code doesn't use whatever it is in `profileA`. Do you mean [-P "profilename"](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Starting_Firefox_or_Thunderbird_with_a_specified_profile) command line switch?

Comment: Yes. How do I use what ever is in profileA ?

Comment: And what is it in `profileA`? Anyway the question doesn't appear to be suited for stackoverflow as it's a matter of using correct parameters listed in the documentation of Firefox and should be moved to superuser.com (and it's probably a duplicate).

Comment: In profileA I have a bookmarked link. I want to open THAT link.